# javascript binding on wp8 and winrt

Tags: javascript, c++, spidermonkey

I am using spidermonkey

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Mozilla/Projects/SpiderMonkey?redirectlocale=en-US&redirectslug=SpiderMonkey

javascript binding on ios and android to develop game.

Just wonder if it is possible to compile spidermonkey on wp8 and winrt both support c++.

Does Microsoft allow this?

If sure,
Is there anyone has compile to create spidermonkey javascript vm on winrt or wp8?

Comment: javascript tag is unnecessary here...

Answer (score 0):

The list of allowed Win32 and COM APIs are posted [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/br205757.aspx).

Any use of APIs outside of that list are not allowed by the Store (and / or will fail at runtime even if side-loaded). If you build the binary and add it to a Store project in Visual Studio, you can check it the WACK (Windows Application Compatibility Kit) to see what banned APIs it is using.

If you'd like to request additional APIs, you can post [here](https://wpdev.uservoice.com/forums/253374-missing-platform-apis).